# NotificationManager don't notify even when notifications are enabled

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I have a app that throws applications. My problem is on my real device(I tested on a virtual device that I'm also using and this problem don't exist, so this is not a code problem), because I didn't disabled my notifications for this app and I can't make the NotificationManager to notify.

I already unnistalled/reistalled the program and checked if the notifications are enabled, nothing worked. I read that changing the package name is the only solution but I can't find a good explanation in how to change, for example, the R folder to the new package. There is no other way?

Answer (score 0):

To change the package name:

1. Right click on the package name.
2. Select the "refactor" option.
3. Select the "rename" option.

Now, you can rename the package.

Comment: in which file do I rename the package?